# Groovy : How do I grep for a string

Tags: groovy, grep, jenkins-groovy

In groovy, I am trying to grep for a string `name:` and add them to a list (unique)

My code:

```
def transitions = jiraGetIssueTransitions idOrKey:  jira_id
echo transitions.data
def valid_transitions = transitions.data.grep("name:")
echo "valid_transitions : ${valid_transitions}.data"
```

Current Output of `transitions.data`:

```
[expand:transitions, transitions:[[id:111, name:Apple to:[self:https://abc.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/status/10700, description:, iconUrl:https://abc.atlassian.net/images/icons/statuses/generic.png, name:Apple, id:10700, statusCategory:[self:https://abc.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/statuscategory/2, id:2, key:new, colorName:blue-gray, name:To Do]], hasScreen:false, isGlobal:true, isInitial:false, isConditional:false, fields:[:]], [id:161, name:Banana, to:[self:https://abc.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/status/11600, description:, iconUrl:https://abc.atlassian.net/images/icons/statuses/generic.png, name:Banana, id:11600, statusCategory:[self:https://abc.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/statuscategory/3, id:3, key:done, colorName:green, name:Done]], hasScreen:false, isGlobal:true, isInitial:false, isConditional:false, fields:[:]], [id:101, name:Mango, to:[self:https://abc.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/status/10707, description:, iconUrl:https://abc.atlassian.net/images/icons/statuses/generic.png, name:Mango, id:10707, statusCategory:[self:https://abc.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/statuscategory/4, id:4, key:indeterminate, colorName:yellow, name:In Progress]], hasScreen:false, isGlobal:false, isInitial:false, isConditional:false, fields:[:]]]]
```

Expected output:

```
 valid_transitions : ['Apple', 'Banana' , 'Mango']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you "output" there is the toString of the already "good" data.  So a `grep` is wrong.  Just use the data directly: `transitions.data.transitions*.name`